# Setting up a persistent connection using node.js

Tags: node.js, persistent-connection

i am having difficulty finding a solution for the following problem statement
**Implement a simple web server that will support persistent connection i.e. will honour the      HTTP header “Connection: keep-alive”.  Thus, when the browser makes the next HTTP request on same TCP connection, the next page should be served.**

So i was wondering , is this possible using node.js? Any help is much appreciated . Thank you

Comment: *Is this possible using node.js* -> Yes

Comment: Please can you give me little more information ? How do i go around doing this?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I check this out